# Skip SignIn page with next-auth.js to go directly to provider

Tags: authentication, okta, next-auth

I am using Okta with next-auth.js. Since I'm only using 1 providers (I will be using more providers inside Okta login), may I just skip this page and go directly to Okta login page? If yes, how?
[image]

Comment: Up with this question. I'm trying to skip this page as well. Per documentation: "If you want to create a custom sign in link you can link to /api/auth/signin/[provider] which will sign in the user in directly with that provider."

I used `<a href="/api/auth/signin/google">Sign in with Google</a>` with no avail. Still pushing me at the default login page

Comment: UPDATE: I have raised the issue here: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/1582

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can utilize `signIn` to skip directly to the provider sign in page

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => signIn([provider])}>Sign in with Provider</a>
```

Replace `provider` with the `provider.id` you want to use. In your scenario, it'll be `signIn('okta')`

refer: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signin

Comment: This does not work inside getStaticProps or getServerSideProps

Comment: works perfectly